# Rally: How to generate an API Key?

Tags: rally

I'm trying to follow the Java example on GitHub for using the RallyRestApi in java.  The first line of code creates a RallyRestApi object using two parameters.  The first is the server, but I cannot figure out how to generate an 'apiKey'.  Can someone share how this is done?

Here is the example I'm following
https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide

Comment: "#Using api keys? -- currently rally1 only
Go to https://rally1.rallydev.com/login
You can generate an api key on this site and use it *instead* of username and password" as seen in https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby, must work both languages

Comment: @G.Mendes Welcome to the StackExchange network. Here we post answers as, erm, answers. Comments are great for clarifying questions but a question/answer page should be useful without any of the comments. I'll gladly delete my answer if you post yours instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment in the original question above should be the accepted answer.  For what it's worth however there is still a constructor which takes server, username, password as well (although this is considered deprecated in favor of the api key approach)

```
//preferred
RallyRestApi api = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com", "myAPIKey");

//deprecated, but still possible
RallyRestApi api = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com", "username", "password");
```

Comment: Agree, the comment on the original post is the right answer, but comments cannot be marked as answers.  I used the deprecated method until I got the link from G.Mendes's comment.

Answer (score 12):

Go to https://rally1.rallydev.com/login. You can generate api keys there. It'd be awesome if they noted that in their getting started guides.

Answer (score 0):

```
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi();
restApi.AuthenticateWithApiKey("Your Key", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", null);
```

The above is how to use the API key using C#. It's probably very similar for Java. (The null is a proxy, adjust for your needs).